# How to debug from android vitals?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android, how can we locate error from ANRs & crashes in android studio?
I got an error like this

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:    at com.meevalsoft.astroguide.EditChart.a (Unknown Source:147)
>    at com.meevalsoft.astroguide.EditChart.onCreate (Unknown Source:264)
>    at (Activity.java:7378)
>    at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7369)
>    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreat (Instrumentation.java:1271)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3167)   >  at .CPU   at .23   at .16   at .11   at
>   1.6   at 3.6   at 2.9   at 2.4   at 2.3   at 2.2   at .0   at 2.1   at 1.8   at 1.8   at 1.4   at 1.4   at 1.3   at 0.4   at .1   at .1   at 0.7   at 0.3   at 0.7   at 0.2   at 0.5   at 0.5   at 0.5

How to locate error causing line?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the stack trace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), then click in the top menu inside Android Studio -> "Analyze" -> "Analyze Stack Trace or Heap Dump" then paste the stack trace and click ok.